# Remove items that contain 'XXX' in group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a group_concat, but I would like to only return items that have a specific value in the grouping.

```
select id, name, group_concat(tag_name) as tags
from base_table
left join tags_table on base_tabe.id = tags_table.base_table_id
group by base_table.id
```

I then could get something like this:

```
id   name           tags
----------------------------------
1    Some Name 1    tag1,tag2,tag3
2    Some Name 2    tag1,tag4,tag5
3    Some Name 3    tag5
```

I would like to filter that to only items that have `tag1` as a tag, which in this case I would no longer have the 3rd row in this example.

The only thing I can think of is using a having like this:

```
having tags like '%tag1%'
```

This however, catches things that are in the middle of words, which would then filter those out as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find_in_set` function to search value in comma separated text

```
Having find_in_set('tag1', tags_column) > 0
```

Comment: Well, you can think of it that way - or as all rows that "don't not have tag1"